# Unable to Find Cause of Transparent Box with Border on Deskop

Tags: windows-7, desktop

What is causing this transparent box with a border to appear on my desktop and how do I prevent it from coming back? I have tried dragging it, changing the background, and anything I can think of to find out more about this box. The box does go away when I restart Windows, but randomly reappears.

[image: Sample of Unknown Box]

Edit: This only appears on one of my two screens (the left one).

Comment: how about going through processes (Task Manager -> Processes) and kill all suspicious things one by one? until you will come over Explorer

Comment: Once it comes up I'll have to try that again. I believe I tried it once but I'll try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by AirDroid 3 (AirDroid.exe Process).
‍ 
The border is the same size as the main window of Airdroid. This was found using [@aandreev's comment](https://superuser.com/q/890404/150988#comment1190368_890404) by closing all processes one by one.

[image: AirDroid 3 Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. This was bothering me for quite a while. About time they fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when AirDroid was set to automatically start with Windows (8.1 Pro x64).

I disabled this through settings and the problem no longer occurs.

Answer (score -1):

[I think I know what it is. It appears to be some sort of bug in the Windows OS. I thought the answer give by @aandreev made no sense and then I started closing processes, and with me it stopped on Steam, which is also set to start with Windows (10 pro x64). So what happens is that when it glitches, only by closing the process that's (probably) starting before the Explorer, is when the box disappear from your desktop view.][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g6oS.png